# creating new intent error

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open a new activity when i click on an imageview.

**MainActivity:**

```
public void menu (View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

**Menu:**

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    }
}
```

When I run the app and i click on the imageview the app crashes and gives the **error**:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
```

As these answeres suggest:

[error on creating new intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183030/error-on-creating-new-intent)

[Creating new activity, Intent error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190625/creating-new-activity-intent-error)

**P.S** I changed my code but it still gave the same error.this seems like a very stupid mistake of mine.Can anyone help me to find my mistake?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this. Create another method with another name, like `goToMenu()`. and put your intent call inside that method and change in xml to `onClick="goToMenu()"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change the name of your activity to `MenuActivity` from `Menu` and then in your MainActivity do it like this

```
public void menu (View view) {
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: welcome, you can upvote it, and if it solved your problem then you can mark it as your answer. So that the question can be closed

Comment: yes, I needed to wait 5 minites after I made the question before i could mark the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First remove this line from ImageView tag in xml;

```
android:onClick="menu"
```

and then You can try below code;

```
  ImageView btn = (ImageView )findViewById(R.id.btn );
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);


            }
        });
```

Comment: what he want is different and what you are suggesting is different. His goal can be achieved by using `android:onClick="menu"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the error was comming from my activity that wasen't named correctly, but thanks a lot for your time :)